Cannot set up ADC for proportionally frequent LED blinking in STM32F103C8T6
I'm trying to set up ADC for STM32F103C8T6 for a LED at PC13, which desired behaviour is blinking with frequency proportional to a potentiometer's resistance at PA0 (a kind of arm assembly hello-world self-study project). I.e. lower resistance => higher frequency rate and vice versa. Besides having set up all necessary clocks according to the Reference Manual, I have also set up PA0 as analog input:
    // Enabling PA0 as analog input (used below by ADC)
    LDR r0, =0x40010800  // GPIOA_CRL, sets up low pins; GPIOA starts from 0x40010800 (Reference Manual, p. 51)
    LDR r1, [r0]
    BIC r1, 0xF << 0  // Clear MODE0 and CNF0 bits for PA0 -> setting analog mode
    STR r1, [r0]

...as well as put ADC1 on through ADON bit:
    // Configuring ADC1
    LDR r0, =0x40012400 + 0x08 // ADC_CR2 register for ADC1 (Reference Manual, p. 240)
    LDR r1, [r0]
    ORR r1, 1 << 0  // ADON bit - power on ADC1
    STR r1, [r0]

The main loop below represents itself a modified version of my first "hello-world" code, where the LED at PC13 just blinked several times per second (I have written down pages within the Reference Manual I used to modify it):
main_loop:
    // ADC conversion
    LDR r0, =0x40012400 + 0x08
    LDR r1, [r0]
    ORR r1, 1 << 22  // SWSTART bit - starts conversion
    STR r1, [r0]

    wait_adc:
        LDR r0, =0x40012400  // ADC_SR register for ADC1 (Reference Manual, p. 237)
        LDR r1, [r0]
        TST r1, 1 << 1  // 
        BEQ wait_adc

    LDR r0, =0x40012400 + 0x4C  // ADC_DR - regular data register (Reference Manual, p. 251)
    LDR r2, [r0]
    LDR r3, =1000000

    MUL r0, r2, r3
    MOV r4, r0

    // Loop for waiting:
    delay_loop:
        SUBS r4, #1
        BNE delay_loop

    // toggle PC13
    LDR r0, =0x40011000 + 0x0c  // GPIOC_ODR
    LDR r1, [r0]
    EOR r1, 1 << 13 // ODR 13 - port 13
    STR r1, [r0]

    B main_loop

As a result, the LED of interest just glows, without reacting to the position of the potentiometer toggle (10 KOhm, connected to A0 with its middle pin, as well as to GND and +3.3 with two other pins). All electrical connections have been checked for not being damaged.
Linker used is GNU ld.
The board is STM32F103C8T6 with Cortex-M3.
Thumb mode enabled, assembly instructions taken from arm's official website.
Reference Manual is RM0008, Rev 21.
I'm trying to learn arm architecture "from below" and would be thankful for your help with understanding the reasons of this failure.

By "the LED just glows" do you mean it flashes at a fixed rate or glows continuously? One way to check if the ADC is working is to make several low bits of an IO register outputs and write the result of the ADC conversion directly to that port. That way you can see if it is reading correctly or not. My guess is that the ADC IO pin isn't quite configured correctly so the input voltage isn't being measured.

Do you have any kind of debugging tools that would let you observe the value read from the ADC? What value are you expecting to get from it, and are you sure that would correspond to a perceptible blink rate? It's a pretty narrow band: above 30 Hz or so, it's too fast for the naked eye to see, and below about 0.1 Hz you'll probably get bored and give up before the first blink.

Dear Martin Brown and Nate Eldredge, thanks a lot for your kindly helping me. The LED glows continuously. So far I have managed to figure out that wait_adc loop is endless, i.e. EOC flag seems to never be set. As far as I understand, this means that conversion actually never ends. Currently I'm trying to find out the reasons for this. It seems to really look like ADC IO pin has not been configured correctly.

Cortex-M in assembly :)?

I have been given a solution at official STM's forums: in order to have ADC started by SWSTART, one needs to set CR2's EXTTRIG bit to 1, and EXTSEL[2:0] bits to 0b111 (0x7). This information is covered by the Reference Manual (RM0008, Rev. 21), p. 240. Now the LED at PC13 blinks and desired, and the solution regarding ADC conversion looks like this:
LDR r0, =0x40012400 + 0x08  // ADC_CR2 register for ADC1 (Reference Manual, p. 240)
LDR r1, [r0]
ORR r1, 1 << 20  // EXTTRIG bit - enables conversion on external trigger (ibid)
ORR r1, 0x7 << 17  // EXTSEL[2:0] bits - should be set to 0b111 (0x7) to start conversion with SWSTART further (ibid)
ORR r1, 1 << 22  // SWSTART bit - starts conversion (ibid)
STR r1, [r0]

